# Issue with MySQL and phpAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, yahoo-api

I am using MySQL 5.1.5 on a Yahoo Sight Server, with phpMyAdmin as the databse interface.

I use the following Query

```
UPDATE table_family SET last_name='Smith' WHERE id=1;
```

Then I get the following error:

---

> Error There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server
>   error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing
>   the problem
>
> ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 34 STR: =\ SQL: UPDATE
>   table_family SET last_name=\'Smith\' WHERE id=1;
>
> SQL query:
>
> UPDATE table_family SET last_name=\'Smith\' WHERE id=1;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '\'Smith\' WHERE id=1' at line 1

---

Ideas?  I feel like its an issue with the database, not with my code.  the last_name field is a varchar(50).  I actually opened a ticket with support on this issue, but it happened to me on two different domains I have with Yahoo, so that makes me think there is more than I know is going on.  I have done this with integer fields that don't require the (') single quote and have had no issues.  I have also run my syntax through a local access database I created just to make sure it wan't a syntax issue.  Worked perfectly first time.  Then I had 2 database guys I know look at it.  They think its good too.  So now I am lost.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Andy

Comment: Seems like some automatic escaping. Could you search the documentation for this behaviour and check it?

Comment: If it's auto escaping .. Try using ticks instead of single quotes?

Comment: Did you enter that query in to the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin or is this a query that hpMyAdmin generated itself when you were in the edit/inline edit view within phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Additionally, I'm unable to reproduce this problem; what phpMyAdmin version are you using?